# Get term of post belong

Tags: php, wordpress

I had this query:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => array('product'), 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'showposts' => 24
);

query_posts( $args );
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-s-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 our-products">
        <a class="products-img" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail('product-size',array('class' => 'img-responsive'));}?></a>
        <a class="products-tit" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
          <h2><b><?php the_title();?></b></h2>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php 
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I need to get tax term of product belong to it.

**Example:**

I had `Category: Products -> Men fashion/Women fashion -> T-shirt -> product A.`
How can i get the term of T-shirt which product A belong to it?

Comment: Do not use `query_posts`, it breaks functionality like the one you need to get working

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress [get_the_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) function for this purpose.

Here is the example:

```
$_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'Your Taxonomy' );
```

In "Your Taxonomy" you put the name of the taxonomy that you just registered e.g. `product-category`

So just like this:

```
$_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'product-category' );
```

And then

```
<?php
     foreach($_terms as $_term) {
?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($_term->slug, 'product-category') ?>">
           <?php echo $_term->name ?>
        </a>
<?php
     }
?>
```

This function [get_term_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) is use for term link.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Pass `$_term` (*complete object*) to `get_term_link()`, the way you are doing it is very expensive because `get_term_link` needs to make a db call to get the term object from the slug. By passing the object, there are no extra db calls to get the object as you have obviously already passed the object ;-)

Comment: Sorry @PieterGoosen but I tried many ways to get term link ... but i got this solution only :)

Comment: its  working 100% if you add right taxonomy name ... above i just give an example

Comment: I was using woocommerce and the taxonomy was product_cat but it didnt show up anything :( btw i solved it with this ty , hope this will help who need it:            <?php 
                $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "names"));
                echo $term_list[0]; 
            ?>